# productCollection Filter with layer navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, product, layered-navigation

I am writing a new product collection in the list.phtml

I want new products to show up on the productlist.. but when i make a new product filter the navigation disappear..

I tried to differents productscollection but still it removes the layer.

this is the code that im using. it works fine but only the layer navigation

```
<?php
    $link = $this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()->getName();

    if($link == "New-In"):
        echo "JA";

        $category = Mage::registry('current_category')->getParentId();
        $todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

        $_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->joinField('category_id','catalog/category_product','category_id','product_id=entity_id',null,'left')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $category))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('date'=>true, 'to'=> $todayDate))
            ->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'news_to_date', 'date'=>true, 'from'=>$todayDate), array('attribute'=>'news_to_date', 'is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null'))),'','left')
            ->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date','desc')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        //$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
        $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    else:
        $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
        $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: This sounds like a PHP/Syntax error. Did you check your system.log/exception.log for further details? Is Developer Mode enabled?

Comment: I looked up.. but no errors on System.log or Exception.log. When i select in the category of magento some products.. then the layer will showed up.